# За сегодня наступает завтра?

Tags: пунктуация, лексика

Неизвестный комментатор известного события пишет: «Беда ораторского пафоса Курта в том, что за сегодня неминуемо наступает завтра».

Простой комментарий терпит такую пунктуацию и т. д., но по большому счёту что тут надо подправить, не утратив краткости, естественно?

Comment: "За сегодня идет завтра", или "после сегодня наступает завтра".

Comment: За сегодня следует завтра, Волга впадает в Каспийское море...

Comment: А за завтра наступит послезавтра?

Comment: Можно сделать стилистическую правку. Можно вообще удалить "сегодня" (завтрашний день неминуем). Банальность нужна ли? Хотя контекст ниже все объясняет. Слово "сегодня" в предш. предложении уже обязательный элемент приема.

Answer (score 3):

Можно написать так:

*Беда ораторского пафоса Курта в том, что **вслед за** сегодня неминуемо наступает завтра.*

Завтра ― несклоняемое существительное, поэтому не различаются формы  В.п. и Т.п. с предлогом ЗА.

Обычно используется форма В.п. с разными значениями.

Answer (score 3):

Со словом "завтра" нужно употреблять глагол в форме будущего времени, так как "завтра" (существительное или наречие) - это то, чего нет в настоящем, "завтра" никогда не наступает, не приходит.  Разве что в предложениях типа *"Ваше бесконечное "завтра" начинает меня раздражать"* его можно употребить с глаголом  настоящего или прошедшего времени,  и то в значении "слово".

***За "сегодня" придёт (наступит) "завтра".*** - Ср.: *За днём сегодняшним придёт (или идёт) день завтрашний*.

(Замечу в скобках: всё предложение, на мой взгляд, находится за пределами русского языка. Исправить его - подвиг.)

Comment: Поддерживаю, но попробую соригинальничать, используя наст. вр.: Книга Альфа Лонэ «Завтра начинается сегодня».

Comment: Хороший каламбур. Если не сказать гениальный).

Answer (score 2):

У комментатора получилась *двусмысленная* и неудобная для восприятия фраза: без контекста не сразу можно понять, идёт ли речь о порядке следования дней (Курт недальновиден и т. п.) или смысл в том, что завтра наступает в качестве неминуемой расплаты "за сегодня" (само это сочетание может восприниматься ещё как "в счёт сегодняшнего дня" - пока предложение не дочитано до конца). Мог бы и просто сказать, что "завтрашний день неминуем", а уж если привлекать к риторике "сегодня", то что-нибудь вроде "сегодня - это сегодня, а завтра будет иначе".

Comment: Не предполагал, что контекст потребуется. Была, правда, лишь предшествующая фраза: "Курт Волкер отметил: «Сегодня Украина является более ... чем когда-либо прежде». Беда ораторского пафоса Курта в том, что за сегодня неминуемо наступает завтра".

Comment: Не проявляет комментатор искусства убеждать: ну кому какая "беда" от текущих своим чередом дней? Лучше бы за другое слово зацепился: "беда в том, что _является_ она такой Курту лишь во снах его".  :)